# how to find coordinate of unknown point given the distance against N known points

Tags: matrices

I am meeting with a problem, say I have already know the coordinates of N points (a1,a2,a3....) in 3D space. And I have a new point, say x. I only know the distances from x to the known N points. Is there an efficient method to find the coordinate of x?

If all of the distance are error-free, I think I can random pick up 3 known points, and compute the coordinate of x. But the distance are not error-free, i.e. if I use different points as reference, the coordinate of x maybe differ a lot.

So I want to use all of those N distance to compute the coordinate of x. Can anyone give some solution or suggestions?

Comment: Typically, $3$ points will not be enough to fix the point anyway.  Usually, when there exists one point with the specified distances, there will exist two such points.

Comment: This looks like a GPS problem, so just try to find out what algorithms they are using.

Comment: One suggested algorithm for $N=4$ (minimize sum of squared errors) is describe in the earlier analogous question *[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1169433/237)*.

Answer (score 1):

See [this wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_estimation_in_sensor_networks) (Location estimation in sensor networks), or read the gazillion papers on the subject :)